# problema com horário de verão e aplicações java no ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, jboss, glassfish

Nesse fim de semana tivemos a mudança para o horário de verão aqui na minha região,  tenho algumas máquinas rodando **ubuntu server 16.04** com aplicações java.

Todas elas com **JBOSS**, **POSTGRES** para uma aplicação e outra com **GLASSFISH**, **MYSQL**.

Se digito o comando `#date` no servidor ele me retorna a data correta, já ajustada para o horário de verão, porém na hora de salvar os registros nas aplicações elas ficam com a data errada!

Por exemplo: Agora são **12:45** se eu gravar algum registro em alguma das aplicações ele grava como **11:45**.

Acredito que seja algum problema com o java, alguém já passou por isso? ou sabe como solucionar?

Utilizo o OPEN **JDK 1.7.0_95**

Comment: Isso pode ser banco de dados também

Comment: Você tem alguma váriavel que armazena a hora no java antes de enviar para o banco de dados? quais as configurações de date do seu banco de dados?

Comment: não tenho nenhuma variavel eu simplesmente uso new Date(); antes da mudança do horario de verão estava tudo certo

Answer (score 2):

Acabei de passar por esse mesmo problema, principalmente porque o horário de verão em 2018 foi estendido até 4 de novembro por conta das eleições.
O java utiliza uma base de dados própria para conhecer os fusos e o início e fim do DST (horário de verão), neste caso, basta atualizá-la usando a ferramenta [TZUpdater](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/tzupdater-download-513681.html) da própria Oracle. O problema é justamente o que você descreveu, você digita date no terminal e a data vem correta, no entanto, se você instancia um date no java e o imprime a informação de hora, vem com uma hora a menos.

Depois que baixar o tzupdater.jar, basta executá-lo da seguinte forma:

```
java -jar tzupdater.jar -l
```

Lembrando que esse comando requer elevação (sudo) porque ele vai atualizar os arquivos da JRE.

No JDK 7 o comando funcionou sem problemas.

No JDK 8, retornou o erro **java.lang.Exception: Failed while parsing file '/tmp/tz.tmp_1/asia'**

Nesse caso, é preciso editar o arquivo e recolocá-lo no tar.gz que ele baixa para atualizar. Eu fiz um shell script [neste outro post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52939175/3335350) que faz a correção necessária no arquivo e realiza a instalação em seguida.

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 2):

Eu passei pelo mesmo problema e solucionei com o seguinte:

- Baixe o [TZUPDATER no site da Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/tzupdater-download-513681.html)
- Depois que baixar o `tzupdater.jar`, basta executá-lo da seguinte forma:

```
sudo java -jar tzupdater.jar  -l https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzdata2018e.tar.gz
```

- Então, reinicie a aplicação java e verifique a data.

Além disso, criei um [playbook](https://github.com/andrez0r5/tzupdater-playbook) para atualizar a JVM de containers.

Comment: Apenas um detalhe: a versão `2018e` do TZDATA não é a mais atual. Você pode consultar o [site da IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) e ver que atualmente a versão mais recente é a [`2018g`](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzdata2018g.tar.gz). Ou você pode usar o link `https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz`, que sempre traz a versão mais atual.

Comment: Sim, mas com a latest tive problemas no CentOS. Por isso, utilizei a 2018e, que funcionou tanto no CentOS como no Debian e Alpine.